# Wrong letter spacing in CSS Web Safe Font

Tags: html, css, spacing, letter

If using combination like: **Ta**, **To**, **Ts**...
The character after **T**  is with different letter spacing, than the same characters, in reverse order :  **aT**, **oT**, **sT** .This is probably used for aesthetic reasons.

Letter spacing can be seen easily when a selection is made.
[image]
[image]

My question is, if there is a font table where letter spacing between two characters, for given font are shown?

```css
span {
    letter-spacing: 0;
    font-family: 'Arial';
    font-size: 70px;
}
```

```html
<span>aTa --- kTk</span>
```

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kerning